# Changing Basemap projection causes data to disappear

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

Exactly as the title says. 
I'm plotting sea ice concentration data and this code:

```
map = Basemap(projection='cyl', lat_0 = lat_0, lon_0 = lon_0,
          llcrnrlon = llcrnrlon, llcrnrlat = llcrnrlat,
          urcrnrlat = urcrnrlat, urcrnrlon = urcrnrlon,
          area_thresh = 1000., resolution='l')
```

Works just fine. https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RcSC.png

But when I try to change the projection:

```
map = Basemap(projection='npstere',boundinglat=10,lon_0=270,resolution='l')
```

I just get a blank map. https://i.stack.imgur.com/s42Q7.png

Am I forgetting something about basemap? I though changing the projection was pretty simple.

Edit: Heres the full code

```
import numpy as np
import math as m
import urllib2
import time
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patheffects as path_effects
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from pydap.client import open_url
from pydap.proxy import ArrayProxy
import scipy
from scipy.ndimage.filters import minimum_filter, maximum_filter

data_url_ice = 'http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/thredds/dodsC/Datasets/noaa.oisst.v2.highres/icec.day.mean.2015.v2.nc'

dataset3 = open_url(data_url_ice)

#############################################################################################
# Get Data
#############################################################################################

# Daily Mean Ice Concentration

Lat_ice = dataset3['lat']
Lon_ice = dataset3['lon']
Time_ice = dataset3['time']
Ice_Conc = dataset3['icec']
Ice_Conc = Ice_Conc[-1,:,:]
Ice_Conc = Ice_Conc.array[:]

Ice_Conc[Ice_Conc < 0] = 0
Ice_Conc = Ice_Conc * 100.

Ice_Conc = Ice_Conc.squeeze()

#############################################################################################
# Colormap
#############################################################################################

vmax_ice = 100.0
cmap_ice = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('mycmap', [(0     / vmax_ice, 'white'),    #-40
                                                         (50.   / vmax_ice, 'yellow'), #-20
                                                         (100.   / vmax_ice, 'blue')]    # 20
                                              )

#############################################################################################
# Map Projection Info
#############################################################################################

lat_0 = 0
lon_0 = 0

llcrnrlat = -90. # (1,1)
llcrnrlon = 0. # (1,1)

urcrnrlat = 90. # (720,361)
urcrnrlon = 359. # (720,361)

# Daily Mean Ice Concentration

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14,14))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
#map = Basemap(projection='ortho', lat_0 = 50, lon_0 = -105,
#              area_thresh = 1000., resolution='i')

map = Basemap(projection='npstere',boundinglat=10,lon_0=270,resolution='l')

#map = Basemap(projection='cyl', lat_0 = lat_0, lon_0 = lon_0,
#              llcrnrlon = llcrnrlon, llcrnrlat = llcrnrlat,
#              urcrnrlat = urcrnrlat, urcrnrlon = urcrnrlon,
#              area_thresh = 1000., resolution='l')

map.drawcoastlines()
map.drawcountries()
map.drawmapboundary()
map.fillcontinents(color='white')

levels = np.linspace(0,100,100)
ticks = [0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]
iceconc = plt.contourf(Lon_ice,Lat_ice,Ice_Conc,levels,cmap=cmap_ice)

# Set Colorbar Text Color
color_bar = map.colorbar(iceconc)
color_bar.set_ticks(ticks)
cbytick_obj = plt.getp(color_bar.ax.axes, 'yticklabels')
plt.setp(cbytick_obj, color='w')

ax.text(0,1.02,'Sea Ice Concentration (%)\n\n',
        verticalalignment='bottom', horizontalalignment='left',
        transform=ax.transAxes, color='w', fontsize=9).set_clip_on(False)
ax.text(0,1.02,'Satellite Measured Daily Mean\n',
        verticalalignment='bottom', horizontalalignment='left',
        transform=ax.transAxes, color='w', fontsize=9).set_clip_on(False)        

plt.savefig('/home/ice_current.png', facecolor='#3e3e3e', bbox_inches='tight')
plt.close("all")
```

Comment: Are you doing this in the commandline? or via a script? How are you putting your data onto the map?

Comment: script. I just added the full code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're forgetting the simplest line, however you haven't shown most of your code so it's hard to guess.
i.e.

```
map = Basemap(projection='cyl', lat_0 = lat_0, lon_0 = lon_0,
          llcrnrlon = llcrnrlon, llcrnrlat = llcrnrlat,
          urcrnrlat = urcrnrlat, urcrnrlon = urcrnrlon,
          area_thresh = 1000., resolution='l')

#valid aproximate coordinates for some map projections
lat = [19.2325]
lon = [-155.3395]

#but the actual map coordinates are
x,y = map(lat, lon)
map.plot(x, y, 'ro', markersize=6)
```

I believe your data is still there, but hasn't been converted to [proper map coordinates](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/mapcoords.html). Notice how in the example they use `m`, your instance of `Basemap` is named `map` in your example so use that. I think it's pretty cool how they did that.

Comment: Oh man I feel dumb. I just needed to add the meshgrid and map it.  Thanks